# Image slider and drop down menus not working togther

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my page code, which contain js for login and registration drop down menu. Slider is added on center of page which start playing on page load.

But before adding slider login and registration portion works fine, but now there clicks are not working. When I remove slider fom this page its works but with slider it didn't. Can anybody help me keeping both these things with full functionality?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
        <head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, 3d, webkit, fallback,               slider, css3, 3d transforms, slices, rotate, box, automatic" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slicebox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.46884.js">    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


<script src="js/index.js"></script>     


    <script type="text/javascript">

function click1(){
            document.getElementById("navPlay").click();
       }



    $('input[type="submit"]').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css('background', '#2ecc71');
    });
   $('input[type="submit"]').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#1abc9c');
   });

   $('#loginform').click(function(){
   $('.login').fadeToggle('slow');
   $(this).toggleClass('green'); 
   });

$(document).mouseup(function (e)


     {
     var container = $(".login");



    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the      container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
    container.hide();
    $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
}  
});

$('#registration').click(function(){
 $('.register').fadeToggle('slow');
$(this).toggleClass('green');
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) 
{  
  var container = $(".register");

  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the   container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the   container
{
    container.hide();
    $('#registration').removeClass('green');
}
});

    </script>

    <Style>
    body{
        background-image:url("./images/bgimg.jpg");
    }
    #h21{
        float:left;
        padding : 20px;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        margin-left:80px;
        font-size: 30px;
        }
    #h22 {  
        padding: 20px;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        margin-left:500px;
        }
    footer {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 50px ;
        margin-top:50px;
        background-color: #34495e;
        margin-bottom:-550px;

    }

    footer p {
        color: #f8f8f8;
        }


    h4 {

        color : #ecf0f1;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0px 20px;
        margin-top:399px;
    }

    </style

</head>


<body onload="click1()"s> 



 <div id="wrap">
   <div id="regbar">
   <div id="navthing">
   <h2 id ="h21">Pictoria </h2>
  <h2 id ="h22"><a href="#" id="loginform">Login</a> | <a href="#"    id="registration">Register</a></h2>
<div class="login">
  <div class="arrow-up"></div>
  <div class="formholder">
    <div class="randompad">
       <fieldset>
         <label name="email">Email</label>
         <input type="email" PlaceHolder="example@example.com" />
         <label name="password" >Password</label>
         <input type="password" PlaceHolder="*******"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Login" />

       </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="register">
  <div class="arrow-up1"></div>
  <div class="formholder1">
    <div class="randompad">
       <fieldset>
         <label name="displayname">Display name</label>
         <input type="text" PlaceHolder="Display name" />

         <label name="username">Username</label>
         <input type="text" PlaceHolder="Username" />

        <label name="password" >Password</label>
         <input type="password" PlaceHolder="*******" />

         <label name="email">Email</label>
         <input type="email" PlaceHolder="example@example.com" />

         <label name="bio" >Bio</label>
         <input type="text" PlaceHolder="About you!" />

         <input type="submit" value="Register" />

       </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 </div>
 </div>



    <div class="container">

        <div class="wrapper">

            <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Creative Lifesaver</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image2"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Honest Entertainer</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Brave Astronaut</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Affectionate Decision Maker</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Faithful Investor</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Groundbreaking Artist</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="image1"/>
                    <div class="sb-description">
                        <h3>Selfless Philantropist</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="shadow" class="shadow"></div>

            <div id="nav-arrows" class="nav-arrows">
                <a href="#">Next</a>
                <a href="#">Previous</a>
            </div>

            <div id="nav-options" class="nav-options" Style="   display:hidden;">
                <span id="navPlay">Play</span>
                <script>
                document.getElementById('navPlay').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                </script>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /wrapper -->

    </div  >
    <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script   src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function() {

            var Page = (function() {

                var $navArrows = $( '#nav-arrows' ).hide(),
                    $navOptions = $( '#nav-options' ).hide(),
                    $shadow = $( '#shadow' ).hide(),
                    slicebox = $( '#sb-slider' ).slicebox( {
                        onReady : function() {

                            $navArrows.show();
                            $navOptions.show();
                            $shadow.show();

                        },
                        orientation : 'h',
                        cuboidsCount : 3
                    } ),

                    init = function() {

                        initEvents();

                    },
                    initEvents = function() {

                        // add navigation events
                        $navArrows.children( ':first' ).on( 'click',   function() {

                            slicebox.next();
                            return false;

                        } );

                        $navArrows.children( ':last' ).on( 'click',  function() {

                            slicebox.previous();
                            return false;

                        } );


                    $( '#navPlay' ).on( 'click', function() {

                            slicebox.play();
                            return false;

                        } );    

                    };

                    return { init : init };

            })();

            Page.init();

        });
    </script>

    <footer>
        <p>     &copy;Copyright 2016 Pictoria`enter code here` | All rights   reserved.  </p>      
</footer>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We miss some CSS informations here. But, it can be a z-index problem. Be sure the slider box isn't over the register/login button.

Comment: It's not on those buttons ..!!

Comment: Can you explain why java functions are not called when i click on login/registration buttons ?

Comment: Try to click on these buttons with a href attribute and tell me if it's the right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try after placing *javascript* code and *.js* file link before the end of *body* tag.